# Como esconder uma div apenas no firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Olá,

De qual maneira é possível fazer esconder uma `<div>` apenas no Firefox e exibir em demais navegadores?

Comment: `var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;`

Answer (score 4):

Segundo [Css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/), você poderia fazer algo assim, considerando seu div com id `meuDiv`:

```css
/* Firefox 2 */
html>/**/body #meuDiv, x:-moz-any-link {
    display: none;
}

/* Firefox 3 */
html>/**/body #meuDiv, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
    display: none;
}

/* Any Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    #meuDiv {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

---

E, caso também queira o contrário:

```css
#meuDiv {
    display: none;
}

/* Firefox 2 */
html>/**/body #meuDiv, x:-moz-any-link {
    display: block;
}

/* Firefox 3 */
html>/**/body #meuDiv, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
    display: block;
}

/* Any Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    #meuDiv {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: e para demostrar uma div apenas no firefox, como é feito?

Comment: @theflash Atualizei minha resposta. A ideia para mostrar a div apenas no firefox é deixar `display: none` por padrão e, depois, utilizando o seletor específico para o firefox, mudar para `display: block`.

Comment: Esclareceu minha dúvida, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a ideia que o **[Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72329/como-esconder-uma-div-apenas-no-firefox#comment148292_72329)** disse:

```js
window.onload = function () {
   var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1; 
  
   if (is_firefox) {
      document.getElementById('divEspecifica').style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

```css
#divEspecifica {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#divTodos {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="divEspecifica">
</div>
<div id="divTodos">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Maicon!